# Why does System.out.println not behave the same as `echo`

Tags: java, terminal

I've been experimenting with OSC52 escape sequences and I'm a bit baffled that I can't get them to work in Java.

If you ran this in a terminal

```
echo '\x1b]52;c;SGVsbG8=\x07'
```

Then "Hello" would be in your clipboard. That works just fine.

For some reason though, doing the same operation in Java does not put it in my clipboard.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\\x1b]52;c;SGVsbG8=\\x07");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is there another mechanism that is more "raw" that would work?

edit:

GIF of the echo version working.

[image: Echoing OSC52 escapes]

Comment: `echo` is an actual program, which has those features implemented in its code. When you print of any other program, your console just displays the output as-is, it is unrelated to echo.

Comment: *...Then "Hello" would be in your clipboard. That works just fine.* Really? For one thing, since that has escape sequences, you would have to invoke `echo -e`. When I do that, it really doesn't do anything, nor place anything on the clipboard

Comment: I mean, I can record a video of me running the echo version if you don't believe me g00se. It did require enabling a permission in my terminal, but I was prompted and that permission seems to be terminal wide and not just for that one program. I'm using iTerm on MacOS Ventura if that helps.

Comment: Right. I'm not sure if my (xfce4) terminal supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that \x1b was being interpreted in my terminal as an escape sequence. In java to write that same character you need to use a unicode escape.

I.E. instead of printing literally

```
\x1b]52;c;SGVsbG8=\x07
```

I needed to use `\u001b` and `\u0007` in the place of `\x1b` and `\x07`

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\u001b]52;c;SGVsbG8=\u0007");
    }
}
```

and that will work.

EDIT:

I published the result of this exploration as a library on Maven Central

https://github.com/bowbahdoe/osc52

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.mccue</groupId>
    <artifactId>osc52</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I could have sworn that Java compilers used to allow hex escape sequences (which would use one backslash of course) but I've been unable to confirm that by searching. Of course `System.out.println("\033]52;c;SGVsbG8=\007");` should also work, but your Unicode-escaped version is better